# EF code first Query madness with include.select

Tags: linq, frameworks, lambda, entity, code-first

I have a big fight with linq
I have a webpage and a zonecontent entity

in my webpage repository i have a method called: GetPageByTitle

here i want to select the page by title and return it.
i try to do this like this:

```
public WebPage GetPageByTitle(string title,string cultureName)
    {
        try
        {

            var entity =
                (from p in GetAll().Include(x => x.Site).Include(x => x.Menu)
                 from c in p.ZoneContents
                 where c.Language.CultureName == cultureName && c.PageTitle == title
                 select new
                            {
                                page = p,
                                zone = c
                            }).SingleOrDefault();

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("There are no visiblepages with the provided title and language");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

now i have a type{Webpage, ZoneContent} and cannot be returned into Webpage
How can i go a step further to combine them into Webpage?

Anyone an idea??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way:

- You don't need to project into an anonymous type if you only want the `WebPage`. Just select only `p`.
- If there is no result you won't get an exception. `SingleOrDefault` will return either the entity or `null`. So simply test for `null` after the query.
- Don't catch the generic exception. If this query throws an unexpected exception let the application crash and fix the bug.

.

```
public WebPage GetPageByTitle(string title,string cultureName)
{
    var webPage =
        (from p in GetAll().Include(x => x.Site).Include(x => x.Menu)
         where p.ZoneContents.Any(c => c.Language.CultureName == cultureName
                                    && c.PageTitle == title)
         select p)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    if (webPage == null)
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "There are no visiblepages with the provided title and language");

    return webPage;
}
```

Comment: `Include` statements are neglected when you do a join.

Comment: @Eranga: True, thanks! I've tried a new version. I have no idea if I can express this without extension methods and lambdas.